# Cargar un windows form en C# por medio de un datagrid cell double click

Tags: c#

Buen día estoy desarrollando un windows form con un grid, el cual se carga por medio de una base de datos, como puedo abrir un nuevo windows form al dar doble click sobre algún registro dentro del datagridview.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola @Alberto, Puedes compartir el código relevante para poder ayudarte? Por favor lee: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Si agregas tu codigo actual recibiras mejores respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola para eso debes programar en el evento "dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick", capturar la fila seleccionada y pasar cada uno de los elementos al formulario que deseas abrir. Supongo que deseas abrir un formulario con los datos seleccionados de la fila del datagridview verdad?

Si eso es lo que deseas, lo único que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente:
Supongamos que tienes un datagridview el cual como mencionas en tu pregunta lo llenas desde tu base de datos, por ejemplo con la tabla producto, la cual contiene 3 campos (Codigo, Nombre y Precio), entonces lo que tendrías que hacer como te dije anteriormente es programar el evento "celldoubleclick" del datagrid, tendrías que usar algo como esto:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            FormSecundario frm = new FormSecundario(); //Instanciamos el Form que abriremos
            frm.txtCodigo.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtProducto.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            frm.txtPrecio.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            frm.Show();  //Mostramos el Form que deseamos abrir.              
        }
```

Ese es el evento del gridview que debes programar, debes llamar a tu formsecundario y pasar a cada uno de sus controles los datos del producto, debes tener en cuenta que los controles donde mostrarás los datos del producto deben tener la propiedad "modifiers"= Public para que puedas acceder desde el formulario principal, con eso quedaría todo listo.

Comment: En efecto, lo que hice fue crear un objeto de la forma que deseaba mostrar y después agregar la función show para mostrarla al hacer doble clic sobre la fila del datagridview, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @Christopher Tavara, como le hago si tengo form abierto y lo quiero pasar ahí.